# Разница между rvalue и lvalue

Tags: c++, vector

Имеется небольшой шаблон функции, который пиинимает в качестве аргументов две ссылки на переменные одинакового типа и меняет их значения местами. При этом когда передаю в функцию два члена вектора типа `int`, то все работает. Но если `vectot<bool>`, то нужно перегрузить функцию и вместо

```
template<typename T>
void fun (T & a, T & b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;

    return;
}
```

Написать

```
template<typename T>
void fun (T && a, T && b)
{
    T temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;

    return;
}
```

Почему так?

Comment: покажите пример кода, который можно скомипировать и попробовать.

Comment: Сейчас, к сожалению не могу - только завтра. Но, по сути, это простая функция перестановки с помощью дополнительной переменной. Ничего больше.

Comment: Что значит **нужно**? Иначе невозможно, или рекомендуется, или что еще?

Comment: знаем мы эти "это простая функция". А по факту шаблон на шаблоне сидит, UB погоняет

Comment: Иначе не возможно

Comment: Вот пример, где **не** нужно (вернее, можно **не**) - https://ideone.com/ULgIMh - что в нем не так? В чем у вас проблема?

Comment: не нужно ничего перегружать, все будет работать и для вектора, просто можно и  другую написать функцию

Comment: Привел весь код в вопросе. Я, если честно, не понимаю зачем это нужно, так как это всего-то 3 строчки - но раз просят, то ладно...

Comment: У вас не работает первый код для вектора? Или в какой-то книге написано, что для вектора надо так, как во втором случае?

Comment: @Mikhailo в вопросе же написано: если в функцию передать члены vector<bool> то первый код не работает, зато работает во втором случае

Comment: Да у вас никакой код работать не будет, потому что вы `temp` просто не используете...

Comment: @Mikhailo работать то будет, просто будет два одинаковых значения) опечатка, исправил

Comment: Кстати говоря, обмен и во втором варианте работает неверно - см. https://ideone.com/3zOJJA

Comment: @Harry странно... если честно: этой функцией не пользовался, просто сразу после того как ее написал понял как обойтись без нее. Интересно, почему так происходит...

Comment: Да все из-за этих исключений `vector<bool>` из общего правила и наличия прокси. Поэтому у него свой `swap` реализован, и это самое верное - для обмена использовать вызов `swap` из родной библиотеки.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Спецификация языка С++ позволяет реализовать `std::vector<bool>` не как обычный вектор из значений `bool`, а как специализированный *упакованный битовый массив*, в котором каждое булевское значение хранится в одном бите. Так как в С++ невозможно создать ссылку на отдельный бит, те методы вектора, которые обычно возвращают ссылку на его элемент (например, `operator []`), в случае `std::vector<bool>` возвращают не ссылку `bool &`, а специальный временный прокси-объект. Этот прокси-объект и реализует чтение и запись отдельного бита.

Т.е. запросто может получиться так, `std::vector<bool>::reference` - это совсем не ссылочный тип `bool &`, а некий определяемый реализацией класс-тип, реализующий/симулирующий поведение обобщенной ссылки. Так как возвращаемый объект этого типа является временным, его невозможно никуда передать по неконстантной lvalue-ссылке. А по rvalue-ссылке - можно.

Это, в частности, означает, что `std::vector<bool>` не обязательно соответствует требованиям, накладываемым на стандартный контейнер.